# Can any iOS app remotely wake a sleeping MacBook Air when the lid is closed?

Tags: macos, ios, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, remote-desktop

I want to be able to access my Macbook Air (Late-2011, Mountain Lion), when the lid is closed (in sleep mode), remotely from my iPhone 4GS.

I have tried using LogMeIn Ignition App but it does not allow you to wake the laptop from sleep.

Is there any other way/solution people are using currently?

Comment: You might be able to keep the LogMeIn app if you set up BackToMy Mac and use the [prompt app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prompt/id421507115?mt=8) (or another ssh app) to wake your mac remotely from sleep first by the incoming ssh traffic. Your router will need to be an Airport or support the [Bonjour sleep proxy protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_Sleep_Proxy) to translate the incoming ssh traffic into a WOL packet.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Air that I leave in [clamshell mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3131) when it is at home.

I also have an AirPort router that connects it to the internet and have it set to have the Mac wake for Wi-Fi access in the Energy Saver system preference pane.

- On iOS, I use the paid app [Screens VNC](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screens-vnc-control-your-computer/id400012962?mt=8) app and configure it to use SSH.
- On the Mac, I use the free [Screens Connect](http://edovia.com/en/screens.html#sc) app in conjunction with the also free [Edovia remote location brokering service](https://screensconnect.com/en/) in case my router gets a new IP address. I don't really need that since I have a fixed IP address, but it simplifies setup and allows me to reach my Mac when it's not at home as well.

This setup works to wake my sleeping Air when I need to access my computer from any of my iOS devices through the internet.

Answer (score -2):

Change the settings on your Mac computer so that the computer keeps running when you close the lid